# Missing Closing Parenthesis error with "USING" Statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I get a `Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'` when I add a specifier to my `USING` statement

Here is an example similar to what I am doing:

```
SELECT * FROM student s JOIN test_result using (s.id) where s.id = 1335;
```

My actual query is much more complex, I have multiple tables that I want to join and some tables have columns with the same name so when I try to `JOIN` one of those tables with a third table, I get a `Error Code: 1052. Column 's.id' in from clause is ambiguous`. When I try to avoid that by specifying which table's `id` I want to use I get a `Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column(s) within the `USING()` clause do not take aliases -  the base idea is that this column should be available in both tables.

This also has the advantage of disambiguating the column, so you don't event need to prefix it with a table alias in the `WHERE` claus.

Just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN test_result ts USING (id) 
WHERE id = 1335;
```

The downside is that, if you use that in a multi-join context where several tables have an `id` column, you don't get to choose from *which* table `id` is picked. This can be troublesome in some situations. In that case, you need to switch back to the `join ... on ...` syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN test_result ts on ts.id = s.id
WHERE id = 1335;
```

Comment: I am sorry you did not get my point, maybe my wording wasn't clear enough, my actual query is more complex and I am joining tables that have columns with similar names and when I am trying to join one of those tables with a third table, I need to specify which `id` I want to use but I can't do so by using a variable within a `USING` statement like `USING (s.id)`

Comment: GMB, I think in WHERE clause you must use alias.

Comment: @SirajAhmadzai: if you want to control *which* `id` is used in the `join`, use the `join ... on ...` syntax. You can't do that with `using`.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: actually, no - as explained in my answer  `using` disambiguates the column name.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment, I think you need an alias based join

```
SELECT *
FROM student s
JOIN test_result t ON t.id = s.id
where s.id = 1335;
```

Comment: yup, I did know about alias joins but I didn't know you can use aliases with a `USING` statement?

Comment: yes I basically wanted to know why I can't use aliases with a `USING()` statement